# ng-model for status picklist

Tags: angularjs

I am the beginner to AngularJs. Finding difficult to understand the concept of ng-model.

I have a controller with `$scope.statusPickList=["Planning" "Execution" "Closed"];`

How this has to be used in the template(html file) in the < Select> statement? Can anyone please help me to understand?

I am trying the below < Select> statement but not getting the picklist entries.

```
< Select type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="statusPickList" 
        ng-options="val as val for val in statusPickList">
 < /select>
```

Comment: If you have trouble with `HTML` and `JavaScript` maybe `AngularJS` is not something you're ready for.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-model` should not be the same as your `select` data source (`statusPickList`). It represents the selected value, not the source. Also, your select HTML and JavaScript is not valid as listed. Here's a minimal modified example using your code:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="val for val in statusPickList">
    </select>
    <div>
      selectedItem = {{selectedItem}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

// JavaScript
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.statusPickList = ["Planning", "Execution", "Closed"];
    $scope.selectedItem = "[not selected]";
});
```

Running live: https://jsfiddle.net/yg1tvxcf/5/

In my example, `selectedItem` is simply a string value on `$scope` that stores whatever is selected in your `select`.

More details at the Angular documentation: [Using select with ngOptions and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.I had gone through the examples at "Using select with ngOptions and setting a default value." before I post here. I know theoretically that ng-model is the ID that binds scope object with the view but while coding, I m not getting exactly what Should I use there. In your comment, you have mentioned to use ng-model="selectedItem". How this 'selectedItem' should be defined/used in controller? I tried using ng-model="selectedItem", didnt get the result. Please help me to understand more on this.  Thanks

Comment: @Usha Please see my edits. I created a simple, minimal example using your code.